# How do I apply changes to the keyboard layout system-wide?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard-layout

In GNOME's keyboard settings there used to be an "Apply System-Wide" option, but in Oneiric this is now no longer the case.

If I use the keyboard settings to change my keyboard layout, the changes are applied only in my session; on the login screen, the old keyboard layout still applies.

How can I apply a different keyboard layout to my entire system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to try the workaround suggested on the launchpad [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/854714).

1. Edit file `/etc/default/keyboard` changing the lines:

   ```
   XKBMODEL="pc105"
   XKBLAYOUT="us"
   XKBVARIANT="intl"
   XKBOPTIONS=""
   ```
2. Run in terminal(<kbd>ALT+T</kbd>) `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`

You can find a list of all the available keyboard layouts in the text file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`.

Comment: Just given that a try, and it does the job perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps:

```
sudo su
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
pkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
service keyboard-setup restart
```

Sometimes (ubuntu login screen for me) just running `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` is not sufficient.