# How to change the default keyboard layout for the login screen?

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I apply changes to the keyboard layout system-wide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68850/how-do-i-apply-changes-to-the-keyboard-layout-system-wide)

Title pretty much says it all. I had it working in 11.04 but the new login screen in 11.10 doesn't seem to have these settings.

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/68850/27554) question.